# Variadic Templates - Recursive function - Last variadic member

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, type-traits

I have the following code with a variadic template copied from: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWvcoIKSaoc @41:30

```
auto sum() { return 0; }

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
auto sum(Head head, Tail... tail)
{
    return head+sum(tail...);
}

int main() {
    cout<< sum(1,2.4) << endl;
    //cout<< sum("hello ", "world") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have two questions: 
1. The sum() function is required here so that I can have a return value for a void passed in when processing the last variadic member - Is it possible to avoid writing this sum() function and have the same functionality?

2. Returning a integer '0' from the sum() function restricts the entire template to be used by integers - Can I extend the same template to concatenate strings?

Thank You

Comment: Does C++14 tag mean you don't want to hear about C++17 fold expressions?

Comment: No - I am ok with C++17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to never allow empty `sum()` calls, and treat the `sum(last)` as the last recursion:

```
template<typename Last>
auto sum(Last last) {
    return last;
}

template<typename Head, typename Second, typename... Tail>
auto sum(Head head, Second second, Tail... tail)
{
    return head + sum(second, tail...);
}

int main() {
    cout<< sum(1,2.4) << endl;
    cout<< sum("hello ", "world") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/BV18tP)

Answer (score 6):

To complement @GuillaumeRacicot answer I prefer to end a recursion with `if constexpr` which is a `c++17` feature.

```
template<typename Head, typename Second, typename... Tail>
auto sum(Head head, Second second, Tail... tail)
{ 
    if constexpr(sizeof...(tail) > 0)
      return head + sum(second, tail...);
    return head + second;
}
```

You can also consider fold expressions:

```
template<typename ...Pack>
auto sum(Pack... args) {
    return (args + ...);
}
```

Comment: If you're in C++17 you might as well use a [fold expression](https://godbolt.org/z/GLJwEn)...

Answer (score 1):

> 1. The `sum()` function is required here so that I can have a return value for a `void` passed in when processing the last variadic member - Is it possible to avoid writing this `sum()` function and have the same functionality?

Every recursion needs a stop condition. In the typical use of recursion with variadic templates (such as in this code), the stop condition is a different overload of the primary template. So you cannot get rid of this entirely.

You can of course replace the stop condition with a different one. Perhaps this one, which will also work for summing things which are not default-constructible:

```
template <class T>
auto sum(T last) { return last; }
```

Of course, there are other approaches to this than recursive variadic templates; such approaches may not need a stop condition.

> 2. Returning a integer '0' from the `sum()` function restricts the entire template to be used by integers - Can I extend the same template to concatenate strings?

No, because the non-template function has no knowledge of which type the previous recursive invocations were dealing with. This can be solved by using the "last item" stop condition I suggested above.

Comment: How does the solution with `return {};` work? I cannot make it work: https://ideone.com/vrCXSb

Comment: @mch Of course, that was an error on my part. Fixed.